# UiTableview insert row every nth result

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I've got a tableview which is populated from a Json feed, row numbers vary. What I want to do is insert an ad every X number of rows. So, for example If the feed returns 23 rows then at row 5,10,15 and 20 I want to insert a row with an advert in it.

At the moment I have no code to show as I don't really know the best way of approaching this problem. One issue I anticipate is that the rows I'm adding are not the same source as the Json feed, I think this may cause an issue with the new row as I don't want to modify the datasource directly, or at least I think I don't.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take NSMutableArray as objects to inserted latter.

```
int numberofrows;
NSMutableArray *objectsToDisplay;
UITableView *tbleView;
```

Just made simple table view as given below:--

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    tbleView=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tbleView.delegate=self;
    tbleView.dataSource=self;

    objectsToDisplay=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A ",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F",@"G",@"H",@"I",@"J",@"K",@"L",@"M",@"N",@"O",@"P",@"Q",@"R",@"S",@"T",@"U",@"V",@"W",@"X",@"Y",@"Z",nil];

    numberofrows=[objectsToDisplay count];
    [self.view addSubview:tbleView];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return numberofrows;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *mycell=[tbleView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];

    if (mycell==nil) {
        mycell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
    }

    mycell.textLabel.text=[objectsToDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return mycell;
}
```

**To insert row after every 5 index use this method**

```
-(IBAction)InsertAdvertizes:(id)sender
{
    for (int i=4;i<numberofrows;i=i+5) {
        [objectsToDisplay insertObject:@"Hello I am Advertize" atIndex:i];
    }

    NSLog(@"object is %@",objectsToDisplay);

    [tbleView reloadData];
}
```

You table will look something like image displayed below:---

[image]

Comment: Thanks, really comprehensive answer. One other point though, if I was to split the tableview in sections containing 5 or less items each and then insert the advert between them, is that possible?  So essentially I'd have something like:

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return <number of times the datasource can be divided by 5>
}

Comment: after how many intervals of row.If you want to add Advertise as sectionHeader?It is possible.just pass number of sections as u described in your comment and reload table.

Comment: Along with no of section pass title for header also to display advertise as section header.

Answer (score 0):

use the

```
tableView: numberOfRowsInSection
```

to set the size of rows

```
columnsToAdd = round(json.objects.count/5)
return json.objects.count+columnsToAdd
```

Then in

```
tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath
```

return your objectColumns or an adColumn

```
when indexPath.row Modulo 5 != 0 => return yourJsonObjectColumns 
else => return yourAdColumn
```

I think this is enought. If you have some code I'll help you again.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The numberOfRowsInSection would mean that essentially I'd be splitting the tableview, is that correct? So I'd have 1-5 for the first section, then an ad, and so on. This sounds ideal, I'll have a look at implementation and will be back if I've more questions.

Comment: I'm trying this but the issue I am having is that the cells I am adding every nth row are being placed on top (or maybe replacing) rows from my data source. How can I insert the rows in addition to my datasource so I'm not losing anything?

Comment: when you do the last step "when indexPath.row Modulo 5 != 0 => return yourJsonObjectColumns 
else => return yourAdColumn" you have to decide: take the next column of my datasource or an "extra row". You can either use 1. an additional counter or 2. fill you datasource with fake columns (i used 2.)